# Make a "multi-page" web survey within a single .php file

Tags: php, html

This is my first day with .php and I'm trying to create a survey from scratch. I already managed to make an index.php where the user inputs their email address and gets forwarded to the actual survey page, which I'm having problems with.

On the survey page, the user is presented with a video. The user is asked to rate this video on a scale from 1 to 5 and then submit their result. This is to be repeated ten times, each time with a different video. I would like to avoid making 10 different .php pages and was wondering if it's possible to make a loop that repeats itself 10 times and reloads the page after every "submit". I embedded the video in the html code like this:

```
<embed src="video1.mov" width="200" height="240" controller="true">
```

But I am not sure how to change to a different video once the submit button is clicked.

This is the code I currently have for the survey:

```
<?PHP
$one = 'unchecked';
$two = 'unchecked';
$three = 'unchecked';
$four = 'unchecked';
$five = 'unchecked';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $selected_radio = $_POST['part1'];
        if ($selected_radio == 'one') {
            $one = 'checked';
        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'two') {
            $two = 'checked';
        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'three') {
            $three = 'checked';
        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'four') {
            $four = 'checked';
        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'five') {
            $five = 'checked';
        }
    }
?>
<FORM NAME ="evalpart1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="setup1.php">
<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name ='part1'  value= 'one' <?PHP print $one; ?>>1
<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name ='part1'  value= 'two' <?PHP print $two; ?>>2
<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name ='part1'  value= 'three' <?PHP print $three; ?>>3
<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name ='part1'  value= 'four' <?PHP print $four; ?>>4
<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name ='part1'  value= 'five' <?PHP print $five; ?>>5
<P>
<INPUT TYPE = "submit" Name = "submit1"  VALUE = "Submit">
</FORM>
```

If you have any tips or even tutorials you could point me too, I would appreciate it very much, my web search hasn't been successful so far.

Comment: Could you embed all 10 videos along with their respective survey questions on a single page ?

Comment: you can generate video number like this `<embed src="video<? echo $n ?>.mov" width="200" height="240" controller="true">` and put an hidden field for the video number like this `<input type="hidden" name="n" value="<? echo $n ?>" />` and `$n = $_POST["n"]; $n++;` after each submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop would only put all the videos on the same page at once. If you want a new one to show after each submit, you can use an array to hold the video filenames, and use a hidden input to keep track of the page number, something like this:

```
$videos = array('video1.mov', 'video2.mov', 'video3.mov');
$pagenumber = 0; //for when post is not set
if(isset($_POST))
{
   //if post is set, get pageid from post
   $pagenumber = intval($_POST['pageid']); //used as index to $videos array
}
$nextpagenumber = intval($pagenumber) + 1; //increment pageid for next page
echo "<embed src='{$videos[$pagenumber]}' width='200' height='240' controller='true'>";
...
<input type='hidden' name='pageid' value='<?php echo $nextpagenumber; ?>' />
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Would the example you've given be part of the code between my php brackets <> or does it come as an extra bit somewhere else? I'm also not quite sure where to put the if condition, I currently have that on top of the one I wrote previously, but I'm wondering if it should rather be nested within or around it.

Answer (score 0):

i personally would put the videos into an array, with $n=0, on submit $n++

```
$videos=array('video1','video2','video3','video4','video5','video6','video7','video8','video9','video10');
```

then use  for each

```
forech ($videos as $video){ ADD YOU RATING SYSTEM HERE}
```

not forgetting a while loop